# Play framework read from json list

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

So I have a structure in json looking like this:

```
{
    "lst": [
        {"name": "foo"},
        {"name": "bar"}
    ]
}
```

I'm having the hardest time converting this to a list of case classes. I'm sure I'm missing something completely obvious...

I have tried this:

```
case class Person(name: String)
implicit val personReads: Reads[Email] = (__ \\  "name").read[String](Person)

// endpoint
def person = Action { request =>
    val person = request.body.asJson.get.as[Seq[Person]]
}
```

which doesn't compile since `read` doesn't return a `FunctionBuilder` which means I can't apply the path to `Person`

Adding a new parameter does compile (changing the json and case class accordingly):

```
case class Person(name: String, age: String)
implicit val personReads: Reads[Email] = (
    (__ \\  "name").read[String]) and 
    (__ \\  "age").read[Int](Person)
```

but throws an exception `Execution exception[[JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsarray),WrappedArray())))))]]` supposedly because it expects a list.

So I tried adding this:

```
implicit val personsReads: Reads[Seq[Person]] = (__ \ "lst").read[Seq[Person]]
```

which then throws a `NullPointer`.

In the end I just want a `Seq[Person]`.
Can anyone point me in the right direction, I'm completely lost to what I'm expected to do here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following instead of giving reads and writes explicitly.

```
import play.api.json.Json

case class Person(name: String)
object Person {
  implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Person]
}

case class Persons(lst: List[Person])

object Persons {
 implicit val personsFormat = Json.format[Persons]
}
```

Now take the json string lets say `jsonStr`

```
Json.parse(jsonStr).validate[Persons] match {
 case JsSuccess(persons, _) => println(persons)
 case JsError(_) => println("parsing failed")
}
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> val str = """{
     |     "lst": [
     |         {"name": "foo"},
     |         {"name": "bar"}
     |     ]
     | }""".stripMargin
str: String =
{
    "lst": [
        {"name": "foo"},
        {"name": "bar"}
    ]
}

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class Person(name: String)
object Person {
  implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Person]
}

case class Persons(lst: List[Person])

object Persons {
 implicit val personsFormat = Json.format[Persons]
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Person
defined object Person
defined class Persons
defined object Persons

scala> val jsonStr = str
jsonStr: String =
{
    "lst": [
        {"name": "foo"},
        {"name": "bar"}
    ]
}

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

Json.parse(jsonStr).validate[Persons] match {
 case JsSuccess(persons, _) => println(persons)
 case JsError(_) => println("parsing failed")
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

Persons(List(Person(foo), Person(bar)))
```

Now when you change your `Person` case class and add `age` field.

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

object Person {
 implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Person]
}
```

Ensure that the json you are trying to parse contains both name and age. If you have only name then you will get parsing error.

Comment: This is great, much cleaner than any example in the play framework documentation. Works like a charm!